# how to style component when website is multi-language & second language is RTL?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, multilingual, tailwind-css

I have project in Nuxt that is multi language (english and persian) .
and as you know Persian is RTL and English LTR
how should I style components when language changed also style change ?
I use tailwindCSS

Answer (score 1):

Rtl is not supported in tailwindcss core.

You have some options to support rtl in your project:

- There is a plugin for this : [tailwindcss-rtl](https://github.com/20lives/tailwindcss-rtl)
- Or you can use [WindiCSS](https://windicss.org/guide/) :

> If you are already familiar with Tailwind CSS, think about Windi CSS as an on-demand alternative to Tailwind, which provides faster load times, fully compatible with Tailwind v2.0 and with a bunch of additional cool features.

[WindiCss Rtl page](https://windicss.org/features/rtl.html)

Comment: actually i use DaisyUI for its components , i dont khnow i can use windicss also toghter